# Calculating time within threads

Tags: c++, time

My goal is to calculate the performance of my thread by seeing how long it took to run but I am getting some issues:

My code is as follows:

#include

```
thread() {
   struct timeval start, finish;

   gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
     -- code -- 
   gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

   double dif = ((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec)*0.000001);
   printf("%f", dif);

}
```

I want my code to print in the format of seconds and miliseconds like: 3.252 or something similar but I get something like: 0.1615680.161717.

Does anyone know how to convert this format to the standard x.xxxx seconds version?

Comment: I highly suspect this is not the complete source code. Did you mean to use `&start` twice? Did you mean to omit `\n` from the format string?

Comment: Because there is no `\n` I think in the output there are 2 values concatenated `0.161568` `0.161717`.

Comment: Rather than gettimeofday, take a look at [C++11's `chrono` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). In particular, [the `high_resolution_clock `](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Answer (score 1):

C++11's chrono library makes this easy. How easy? This easy:

Required include:

```
#include <chrono>
```

Thread body:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start, end;
start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
//--code--
end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end-start;
std::cout << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
```

Links to libraries and functions used:

[`chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

[`high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

[`duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

And as an added bonus, it works on more than just Linux.

Answer (score 0):

To print a `double`: `printf("%lf", dif);`

Edit (correction): It doesn't matter if the specifier is `%f` or `%lf`, the argument gets promoted to `double`.

Also you are using inconsistently the variables. Both calls to `gettimeofday` are using `start` variable. Where is `end` used?

Comment: Still gives me the same thing

Comment: `%f` works fine for `double`. Any `float` argument will be promoted to `double` when it goes into the ellipsis, so it's not possible for `printf` to differentiate when obtaining the argument using `va_arg`. It could do something different later like with `%c` (except it's not specified to), but it has to start with a `double` either way.

Comment: @chris At least in `glibc` it seems that `l` is ignored for `lf`. A variable [`is_long` is set](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c#l1603) but after that it is not used when passed to [`__printf_fp`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c#l760)

Comment: @nnn, That seems about right considering %f and %lf are specified to do the same thing.